# Keep Constraints to Content Within a Bootstrap Container / Div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to shrink everything inside a container. I have images that will need to stay a certain width and height. However, if the screen gets smaller all images to start to lose their place and content starts to shrink and sizes start to change. I understand the images/content will be harder to see.

I am using Bootstrap 4 with HTML and CSS d-flex is bootstrap and no-padding is just removing the padding of the default cols give.

[smaller view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydapo.png) [Larger View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vydpv.png)

```
<div class="container" style="min-width: 100%;">
                    <div class="row main-stage" id="main-stage" style="justify-content: center;">
                        <div class="col-12 d-flex no-padding text-center justify-content-center" style="background-color: #fff;">
                            <img src="/assets/img/banner/1200x200Banner.png" alt="" class="p-4" style="min-height: 200px;">
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 d-flex no-padding">
                            <div class="col-2" style="background-color: #fff;">
                                <img  src="/assets/img/banner/400x160Banner.png" alt=""
                                    style="min-height: 400px; max-height: 400px; min-width: 100%; border-top: solid 10px; border-bottom: solid 10px;">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-8" style="background-color: #fff;">
                                <div class="row m-4">
                                    <div class="col-12 text-center">
                                        <img src="/assets/img/banner/200x100banner.png" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row text-center">
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <img src="/assets/img/banner/100x180Banner.png" alt="" >
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-4 text-center">
                                        <img src="/assets/img/banner/200x100banner.png" alt="" >
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <img src="/assets/img/banner/100x180Banner.png" alt="">
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2" style="background-color: #fff;">
                                <img class="" src="/assets/img/banner/400x160Banner.png" alt=""
                                    style="max-height: 400px; border-top: solid 10px; border-bottom: solid 10px;">
                            </div>

                        </div>
                       
                        

                    </div>

                </div>
```

Comment: You have two images; one appears to be a tablet and the other appears to be a laptop (or desktop display). What happens if someone looks at your page with an old iPhone 5 with a CSS pixel width of 320 pixels? The easiest way to work with Bootstrap is to start with the smallest screen first and *expand* from that layout, rather than thinking of the layout as *shrinking* (Bootstrap is a [mobile-first](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/) framework).

Comment: I think in place of .col-* class you need to use .col-lg-* and .col-md-* class for desktop or tablet view. if you want to make a page for these two device only. if you want to make responsive design for all the view then you can also use .col-sm-* class. it will create a responsive design for all the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code that is a good approach to your request.

[Run code @ codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/8cu5Ar3Gcd)

**Changes**

I have applied different modifications to the code since the nesting of row and container is not a good idea.

The main change to make a fluid movement of the various components is to add the container-fluid tag at the beginning.

If you could create the ilusion of fluid movement, you have to add "img-fluid" class for images, and all componentes will be dynamically adapting the code to different screen sizes.

There are also [flex concepts](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/) applied that were not well resolved.

Rather than working with flex in the code, try to create a styles page of the type scss, so that you can dynamically solve this. Bootstrap 4 incorporates flex into its code, but leaves some spaces uncovered that you can take advantage of from the style pages. I suggest you see the following page where this is explained in detail. see [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Good luck!